# className:hover #myID {style}

Tags: html, css, hover

Im trying to have some description text on mye card(box) move up 10px when I hover over it like on the pictures. But for some reason the city name text and the button follows it.

[No hover in this card (IMG)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lg8up.png)
[Here is hover (IMG)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LRl4.png)

as u can see on the second img. the button jumps up too.

HTML code for the card with the text and city name and button

```
    <div class="cards_container">
    <div class="card" id="card_oslo">
      <p class="cardCityInfo">
        Oslo er et kult sted <br> hvor det er mange <br>
        turister året rundt. <br> Så dra og besøk.
      </p>
      <h4 class="card_text">Oslo</h4>
      <a href="#"><h5 id="btn_card">Se mer</h5></a>
    </div>
```

CSS code for the style, and how I tried to code the :hover effect on the desc. text on the cards. ".card:hover .cardCityInfo" is the one where I'm trying to get the hover on just the text

```
    .cardCityInfo{
      font-size: 1.1rem;
      font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
      color: #fff;
      text-align: center;
      z-index: 5;
      margin-top: 100px;
      opacity: 0;
      }

    .card:hover{
      box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px rgba(0,0,0,.7);
      transition: .5s;
      }

    .card:hover .cardCityInfo{
      opacity: 0.9 !important;
      transition: .5s;
      margin-top: 90px;
      }

    .card:hover .card_text{
      color: #fff;
      transition: .5s;
      }
```

Here is how the card looks in CSS if that does anything...

```
    .card {
      position:relative;
      width: 315px;
      height: 300px;
      background-size: contain;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-color: #fff;
      border-radius: 5px;
      margin: 20px 10px;
      float: left;
      /*box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px #999;*/
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change the margin of an element, you change everything else that follows it in the same document flow. To change that you can just use transform on the element, so instead of

```
.card:hover .cardCityInfo{
  margin-top: 90px;
}
```

you use the transform there:

```
.card:hover .cardCityInfo{
  transform: translateY(-10px);
}
```

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/1jgLzdn4/